# Visual Studio 2010 is not supporting CSS3 tags after downloading CSS3 IntelliSense

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

After installing CSS3 IntelliSense schema, Visual Studio is showing CSS3 in a drop down menu, but VS 2010 is not selecting CSS3 and thus not supporting "transition and transform properties", and giving an error. I saw the HTML5 schema file, it already points to CSS3 schema , but the error is still there ...

I am defining these classes, and get an error:

```
.hovereffect .overlay { 
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0,1);
    transform: scale(0,1); }
.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1); }
```

Please help

Comment: what is the error? and codes you used.

Comment: i am defining these classes ,and get error
.hovereffect .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden; width: 80%;  height: 80%;  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0,1);
  transform: scale(0,1);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments section, edit your post instead. Currently the code is unreadable.

Comment: I am using transform ,transition properties of css 3.there is no problem in code while the dropdown menu is showing css3 option in visual studio, but it doesn't select css3